# Response time degraded..Need suggestion on improving performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, heroku

I am new to heroku and ruby and my task in current project is to improve the performance of the app running on heroku.

We have a app running on heroku built on Ruby on Rails using DatabaseDotCom gem.

From the last few weeks users are complaining that the app is very slow and when I log into the dashboard and see the activity there is this warning/error message appearing:

> App Alerts Response time degraded. Compared to this day last week,
>   your median response time has increased 341%, and your 95th percentile
>   response time has increased 122%.

I am new to heroku so I am posting all the relevant info. Here is our setup looks like:

Dynos:

[image]

General Info:

```
Region          US
Stack           cedar-10
Framework       Ruby
Repo size       1.0MB
Slug size       25.8MB of 300MB
```

Database:

```
Plan            Dev
Status          Available
Primary         Yes 
Connections     2/20    
Data Size       8.1 MB
Tables          2
PG Version      9.3.6
Created         2014-07-29T18:10:00Z
Rollback        Unsupported
Rows            2055/10000 (In compliance)
```

Could somebody please suggest me if it is time to add one more dyno or tune the application to improve the performance.

or should I open a ticket with heroku and see what they suggest?

**Note:** I posted the same question on heroku forum and I haven't received any suggestion so checking on SO. Here is the link:
https://discussion.heroku.com/t/response-time-degraded-need-suggestion-on-improving-performance/1192

**EDIT:** This application has just one table with user ID and password and then once logged in, it makes call to salesforce and displays data. It is kind of wrapper to salesforce than giving the users direct access to salesforce.

Comment: You might want to start by reading up on [common rails performance gotchas](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/performance) and how to [profile your application](http://railscasts.com/episodes/368-miniprofiler). You also do not specify how much traffic your site is getting. If it is a small amount of traffic and a small app then the most common culprit is ineffective database queries or the dynos going to sleep.

Comment: If you are new to both Ruby and Heroku then probably you are not the best person to be tasked with performance tuning of a RoR app running on Heroku. You should bring in someone who has some experience with this. If that is not possible, search the web for rails performance monitoring / tuning. There are a lots of well written articles.

Comment: This application does not have much of database, It just has one table with the users Id and password and once the user logs in the application make call to salesforce and displays the data. It is kind of a wrapper to read data from salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

You need to work out exactly what has changed, not have vague high-level numbers.

- Maybe there has been a code change.
- Maybe users do different work at a different part of the month, with transactions that take longer to complete.
- Maybe the SalesForce system is responding slowly.
- Maybe a gem has upgraded.

You need lower level tracing, so hopefully you are using something like NewRelic to trace the transaction performance.